# Code won't print several lists but is showing no errors

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to make a program which allows a user to enter in a 5 digit product number and the program will search the included csv file by that number until it finds it, at which point it will print the corresponding name and price but not the number. In order to get to this point I decided to create a list with each row from the file in it and then print them for troubleshooting, none of them had issues individually printing their lists but when I tried to print all 5 at once it printed the first list then showed 4 empty brackets for the others. The assistant is showing no errors at all and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
import csv

f = open('products.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

next(f)

pNumber = []
pName = []
pDescription = []
pCategory = []
pPrice = []

for row in csv_f:
    pNumber.append(row[0])

for row in csv_f:
    pName.append(row[1])

for row in csv_f:
    pDescription.append(row[2])
    
for row in csv_f:
    pCategory.append(row[3])
    
for row in csv_f:
    pPrice.append(row[4])

print(pNumber)
print(pName)
print(pDescription)
print(pCategory)
print(pPrice)
```

The products csv file looks like this

```
Product #,Name,Description,Category,Price
38500,Backpacking Tent,"2-Person Backpacking Tent - 20D Ripstop Nylon",Outdoor,205.99
27840,Sit-Stand Desk,"Sit-Stand Compact Workstation Desk Converter, 37in",Household,139.99
37992,Mouse,"Dark Matter by Monoprice Rover Optical Gaming Mouse - 6200DPI",Office,19.99
24458,Subwoofer,"15in THX Ultra Certified 1000 Watt Powered Subwoofer",Audio,1280.07
38323,USB Cable,"USB 2.0 Type-C to Type-A Charge & Sync Kevlar-Reinforced Nylon-Braid Cable, 6ft, purple",Office,7.55
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd-5th lists are empty because the first loop read all of the data in the file; there's nothing left to read.  If you want to iterate through the entire file again, you need to reset the cursor position in the file object.

```
f.seek(0)
```

is often the simplest way to do it.

Better yet, store all of your data fields within one loop, rather than reading the entire file for one column at a time.

Even better than *that*, simply read the file straight to a data frame.

Comment: how would I read the file straight to a data frame?

Comment: You would consult the existing PANDAS documentation, or simply search for the answer with your browser.